# Kafka: Can a Topic Be Consumed by Multiple Independent Consumer Groups?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

It's odd that I can't easily find this information online, but I could not.  So, my question is that I have one Kafka topic.  I want 2 consumer groups  independently of each other consume messages from this topic.  So, what I want is that both consumer groups to be able to see and consume all messages independent of each other.

Just to be even more clear, I don't want some messages to be consumed by one consumer group, and some messages to be consumed by the other group; no, I want the 2 groups consume messages as if the other group doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, separate consumer groups are completely independent, so they all see all messages.

Partitioning of resources (topics/partitions) only happen within groups.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "Partitioning of resources (topics/partitions) only happen within groups".  The partitioning and replications of each topic can't change per consumer group; that's decided when you create the topic itself.

Comment: I meant the assignment of partitions to consumers, as in a group only one consumer can be assigned to a partition.